# Tolerability of extremely high acceleration for an extremely short period?

Tags: acceleration, stress-strain

I've been wondering about this for a while. So let's assume a ship accelerates at 1 million G for an extremely short period of time, such that its total velocity change was (say) 1cm/s. Would the ship or its passengers suffer damage, and if so how much? Is there any level of velocity change where immense accelerations are safe/survivable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $g\approx10\,\mathrm{m/s^2}$ for the standard acceleration of gravity on Earth, so $a=10^7\,\mathrm{m/s^2}$
and
$$\Delta v=a\Delta t$$
we get $\Delta t=1\times10^{-9}\,\mathrm{s}$, that is, the extremely short period is about 1 nanosecond.

Plugging that into
$$\Delta s=\frac12a\Delta t^2$$
we get that the object moves 5 picometres, 0.1 the Bohr radius of the hydrogen atom. I don't think the ship or its passengers will notice that tiny movement. ;)

Comment: Nice answer. +1 from me.

Comment: yes, clear and simple, +1 from me too.

Comment: Maybe their displacement during the period of acceleration would be only 0.1 Bohr radius of the hydrogen atom, but, if the ship velocity suddenly changed by 1 cm/sec, they would certainly feel this..

Comment: @Chet Maybe, but 1 cm/s is only 0.036 km/h. I don't *think* I'd feel that, no matter how fast or slow it happened.

Comment: Maybe you don't think you would feel it, but I think I would feel it if the floor suddenly started moving under me at 1 cm/sec.

Comment: @Chet Clearly, we need to do an experiment. ;) But how do we induce an acceleration of $a=10^7\,\mathrm{m/s^2}$ for 1 nanosecond?

Comment: We don't need to do that. All we need to do is to jump to 1 cm/sec in a relatively short time, like say 1 millisecond. Assuming a kinetic friction coefficient of, say, 0.2, our feet would have applied to them a frictional force to accelerate at only 0.2g = 2 m/sec^2. So for our bodies to reach final velocity, it would require about 5 msec. Our bodies (the bottom of our feet) would experience a frictional force of 0.2mg horizontally, or nominally 200 N, over this time interval.

Comment: @Chet You make good points. I'll give this further thought, and invite input from others on this interesting question.